# Sony Vaio 13 Pro - Blank screen on power on

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, sony-vaio

I bought my Sony Vaio 13 Pro SVP1321M2E a little more than two years ago and it's been running great - until the fan started to make an incredible amount of noise. I replaced the fan myself and after that it started, at times, to power on but with a completely blank screen. However after a few restarts the screen came on again and everything was fine. I use suspend quite a lot and because of that my computer is "on" for many weeks at a time, before restart (most likely due to a new Linux kernel being installed since I'm a Ubuntu user).

Earlier this week, much to my disappointment, I restarted my laptop and since then it was refused to power up the screen again. I disassembled it - everything looks as it should, smells as it should; I've replaced the thermal paste, even replaced the new fan with the old but no go.

The computer powers up, starts the fan, the keyboard backlight, power indication and all, but the screen is completely black. Blank. Nothing.

I consider it odd since the laptop haw been working great for months since I replaced the fan. I suspend it, use it, suspend it, use, many times every day without worry. Then the screen works. But now, nothing. I've tried with and without the battery, using AC only, nothing. Removing all kinds of wires and trying, nothing; then putting them back, nothing.

Maybe it is that some stage of the BIOS or POST doesn't "go live". Could it be the BIOS battery?

Connecting a external monitor using HDMI is no change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace the thermal paste?

Comment: Yes I did. Once using new fan, then when switching back to old, then a third time and a fourth after doing the reflow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the machine is booting up without display? you can check if your able to hear login sound or hard disk is reading or trying to ping from another machine by getting IP from your router list.
If it does then try connecting HDMI cable or vga monitor and use keyboard shortcut to switch after booting and see if it makes any difference.
Otherwise unplug the LCD cable from motherboard of notebook and see if does boot and changes the monitor to vga or HDMI?
Also try to change the brightness from keyboard.

Comment: I am  unable to confirm, nor do I believe it goes anywhere when started. Also the drive is a M.2 SSD so it is silent. I need to type three passwords for the computer to get online so I can't get anywhere with that either. Also, I've tried external monitors (both using HDMI and HDMI2VGA adapter); pressing the keyboard shortcut to switch, without any success. Brightness as well. And unplugged the internal LCD cable.. Sorry, but thank you :)

Comment: Then try to use heat gun and re-heat the motherboard and see if it does work for you. BUT be careful as this can render your motherboard completely dead if you are not aware how to do it.

Comment: Aha, that sounds kind a cool. I'll see if I can get a heat gun from somewhere. I suppose an hair dryer wont do the trick(?).

Comment: you can try, with hair dryer you need to be sure and extra careful also requires a lot time than heat gun as that allows you to adjust temperature and flow of hot air too. But be careful. do update with your outcome.

Comment: What about putting the motherboard in the oven?

Comment: Entirely your call :)

Comment: The oven it is! ;) http://www.computerrepairtips.net/how-to-reflow-a-laptop-motherboard/

Comment: It did no change.. :(